# Fading an HTML <a> anchor tag with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Link 1**

```
<a class="LinkN1" id="HomeLink" href="./" >Home</a>
```

**Link 1 CSS**

```
.LinkN1{
text-decoration:none;
color:silver;
transition: color .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: color .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: color .25s ease-in-out;
width:70px;
text-align:center;
padding:5px;
height:20px;
background-color:#06C;
margin-left:103px;
margin-top:-30px;
float:left;
border-left:solid 3px silver;
}

.LinkN1:hover{
color:orange;
background-color:#333;

}
```

What i would like to do is fade the background color of the link **LinkN1** from **#06C** to **#333** in only **CSS**, but if this can be done is **Javascript** then i will use that.

**NOTE** SOLVED.

It was a transition mistake i did intend to animate both font and background colors hence *color:* and *background-color:* in the **CSS**.

Shaun. Edit- Only noticed comments now, thank you for the corrections, they are welcomed;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You animated the font colors, not the background:

```
transition:             color .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:        color .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:     color .25s ease-in-out;
```

By Animating all css values, you're sure to get the background animated aswell:

```
transition:             all .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:        all .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:     all .25s ease-in-out;}
```

**Solution html:**

```css
.LinkN1 {
    text-decoration:        none;
    color:                  silver;
    transition:             all .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:        all .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:     all .25s ease-in-out;
    width:                  70px;
    text-align:             center;
    padding:                5px;
    height:                 20px;
    background-color:       #06C;
    margin-left:            103px;
    margin-top:             -30px;
    float:                  left;
    border-left:            solid 3px silver;
}

.LinkN1:hover {
    color:                  orange;
    background-color:       #333;
}
```

```html
<a class="LinkN1" id="HomeLink" href="./" >Home</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

To animate the color and background-color change transition to:

```
transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, color .25s ease-in-out;
```

You can use `transition: all;` but that will also animate any other property change.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define transition for background-color not the font color. So just change your CSS to

```
.LinkN1{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:silver;
  transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
  width:70px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:#06C;
  margin-left:103px;
  margin-top:-30px;
  float:left;
  border-left:solid 3px silver;
}
```